# Delete Tabs Programmatically Dotnetnuke

Tags: tabs, dotnetnuke

I am trying to delete tabs Programmatically using these statements, but it is not deleting from the database:

```
controller.DeleteTab(tab.TabID, DNN.GetPMB(Me).PortalId)
```

Comment: What *does* happen? Further more, what is your *question*?

Answer (score 2):

TabController.DeleteTab will delete a tab if it is not the parent of another tab.  This method results in a physical deletion, the tab is not simply marked as deleted.

Comment: It looks like the `DeleteTab` method off of `TabController` calls the `DeleteTab` stored procedure, which actually does delete the tab from the database, rather than setting the `IsDeleted` flag.  Looks like the parent/child issue is the culprit (didn't know about that one, thanks!)